# Writing AR(1) as a MA($\infty$) process

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, autoregressive, moving-average

The AR(1) process is

> $$
> X_t = \phi X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t
> $$

if we use this formula recursively, we get
$$
X_t = \phi(\phi X_{t-2} + \varepsilon_{t-1}) + \varepsilon_t = \phi^2X_{t-2} + \phi\varepsilon_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t = \cdots = \phi^k X_{t-k} + \sum_{j=0}^k \phi^j\varepsilon_{t-j}
$$

If we let $k\to\infty$, we get
$$
X_t = \lim_{k\to\infty}(\phi^k X_{t-k} + \sum_{j=0}^k \phi^j\varepsilon_{t-j}) = \lim_{k\to\infty}(\phi^k X_{t-k}) + \sum_{j=0}^\infty \phi^j\varepsilon_{t-j}
$$
The duality between AR(1) and MA($\infty$) states that there is an equivalence between the two, and that we can write $X_t$ as

> $$
> X_t = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \phi^j\varepsilon_{t-j}
> $$

The difference between the two results is the term $\lim_{k\to\infty}(\phi^k X_{t-k})$, which should be zero, but how do I show this?

Assuming $|\phi| < 1$, we have that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\phi^k = 0$ of course, but I don't see why $\lim_{k\to\infty} X_{t-k} < \infty$? Does convergence asuume the law of large numbers, or is there another way to show equivalence?

---

I know there is a proof which inverts the lag operator $1-B$, but I didn't find any justification for why the operator can even be inverted, so I wanted an alternative proof, as the one above.

Comment: There are some issues with your indices - summations should start at $j=0$ and it should then be $\epsilon_{t-j}$, not $\epsilon_{t-k}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual sense in which convergence is understood in this case is in *mean square*:

$$
E[Y_t-(\epsilon_t+\phi\epsilon_{t-1}+\phi^2\epsilon_{t-2} +\ldots+\phi^j\epsilon_{t-j})]^2=\phi^{2(j+1)} E[Y_{t-j-1}]^2
$$
If $Y_t$ is stationary
$$
E[Y_{t-j-1}]^2=\gamma_0+\mu^2
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{j\to\infty}E[Y_t-(\epsilon_t+\phi\epsilon_{t-1}+\phi^2\epsilon_{t-2} +\ldots+\phi^j\epsilon_{t-j})]^2=0
$$

Comment: So we would use the weak law of large numbers, i.e. $\lim_{j\to\infty} E(\phi^j X_{t-j})^2 = 0$?

Comment: The WLLN usually refers to sample size going to infinity, whereas in this situation, the number of lags goes to infinity. I rather read it as saying that the mean of the squared difference vanishes.

Answer (score 2):

You are right to be suspicious of this step, and in fact, without further assumptions to limit the size of $X_{-\infty}$ you cannot get the required form.  Remember that the recursive equation for the AR model is insufficient to yield the joint distribution of the process.  (You need to impose a distribution for the error process, and even then, you either need to impose stationarity or specify an initial distribution that leads to some non-stationary model.)  If you only have this recursive equation, there is no reason that the time-series values could not explode out to large values as $t \rightarrow -\infty$.

For example, the deterministic non-stationary AR process $X_t = \phi^t$ satisfies the recursive equation you have specified (with zero errors), and in this case you have $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} X_{t-k} = \infty$.  In this model, for any $\phi \neq 0$ you also have:

$$\phi^k X_{t-k} = \phi^k \phi^{t-k} = \phi^t \neq 0.$$

Since the errors are zero in this deterministic model, this gives you the limiting result:

$$X_t = \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \phi^k \varepsilon_{t-k}}_{0} + \underbrace{\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \phi^k X_{t-k}}_{\phi^t}. \\[6pt]$$

Clearly, in this case, the limiting term is non-zero, and cannot be removed from the result.  If you would like to be able to remove this last term, you need to add further assumptions to your model (e.g, stationarity).

Comment: I have the same reasoning, However, when I transform $(1 - \phi L)X_{t} = \varepsilon_t$ into $X_{t} = (1 - \phi L)^{-1} \varepsilon_{t}$ when $|\phi| < 1$, it implies that $X_{t}$ is stationary, and the limiting term you showed above converges to 0. I am sure there is something wrong with my reasoning. Can you show it to me as it is important for me? Thank you so much!